# Edit cell above the current one python csv

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with open('timetable.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        rowId = row[0]
        pmp = row[1]

        for item in row:
            if item != "" and "/" in item:
                class = item
                editRow = row[0] - 1
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------
1 | name | ----- | class | ----- |
2 |      |       | class_id / class_name |       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I have this code. I am looking for the 2nd row and I get the cell that has class_id / class_name. But the stuff I tried to go one row above to the same cell so I can paste the text from row 2 to row 1 isn't working

The desired output would be:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
1 | name | ----- | class / class_id / class_name | ----- |
2 |      |       | class_id / class_name |       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: 1) Is the first row the CSV header? 2) If you are trying to back up a row this `row[0] - 1` is not going to work as `row[0]` is the first column in the current row and `-1` is just going to subtract from the column value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - 1) The if statement is true on the 2nd row (always) so that is not an issue.

Comment: It could be an issue if you want to write over the first row and that is the header.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - It's not a header so I am ok I think. my issue isn't the header tho it's how I am supposed to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of all previously processed rows in a variable `all_rows`. Then, the previous row is accessible as `all_rows[-1]`:

```
import csv
with open('timetable.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|")
    all_rows = []
    for row in reader:
        # skip lines containing only hyphens 
        if len(row) == 1:
            all_rows.append(row)
            continue

        rowId = row[0]
        pmp = row[1]

        for col_num, item in enumerate(row):
            if all_rows and len(all_rows[-1]) > 1 and "/" in item:
                prev_row = all_rows[-1]
                prev_row[col_num] += " / " + item 

        all_rows.append(row)
```

Writing this back to a file with the correct delimiter gives your desired output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
1 | name | ----- | class  /  class_id / class_name | ----- |
2 |      |       | class_id / class_name |       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##rVI9b8IwEN39K05hScRn2q0S3Zk6dIwiZJFLsXDsyDZESPx3enZMAhJdUL2c/e753bvTtWe31@r9ehVNq40DoVm87eyJMQtrSJIkhwso3iCFuT8Ud5JbO77ZG93DieFG2YoKlvHaS5DeIDx/7bB/NXTLsxfdhIY64fY0vcW3M0L9bL5SmwG3foq1kPjBfAWDvEJDnRO66B9pJMygQika4dCsk0uSBT6Xcmt052dVlAGptQFCQKgo1gv7MwF7EC1IoZDKauW4UOQEtJJn2J/bPSoLA1vUIFGlpJXBeg35qHNfeMHbFlUVaA8Ery/UEdmAEmVTkVGKxaoc4LZpI5iXI9m3sdNyq47NDKjnxjeE9ELDHYZyj4bI7jAMrqrg/QYU87zM4BPykEmWiRfzoo8SwY3Bk/9Dlu5//8kroskSprSutDYJTHu/Yy9PZ8UmpCGUG0xmTzYkLIg@uro32sXF6IzfgtQnnm5FFxmkei/vU/7PwiIe0lXP7U0E2O9LmmXX6y8)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get errors on the 2nd line from last

Comment: prev_row[col_num+extra_index] = new_item.strip()

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Same error as last time

Comment: I guess it runs on there but that's not what I need. I need to move class_id / class_name into the same cell id but not the same row id. I need it 1 row up. So the final result would be something along the lines of
```
-------------------------------------------------------
1 | name | ----- | class /  class_id / class_name | ----- |
2 |      |       | class_id / class_name |       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```
My bad if I wasn't clear enough

Comment: Please edit your desired output in your question. It's not very clear as a comment, as you can see @ImDarkk. I'll edit my code in a minute

Comment: Updated it with the desired output

Comment: the updated code still doesn't work for me but thank you for trying.

Comment: @ImDarkk I'm done making changes. This code gives the exact output you need. I messed up when pasting my code from another tab.

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you, please post an example and show what doesn't work, and I can try to help you figure out why

Comment: printing all_rows shows the original input, rather than the updated text

Comment: Okay, I really don't know why that could be the case. The TIO link in my answer uses _exactly_ your input (including the `-------` lines) and prints _exactly_ the output you need, so I'm sure my code works correctly for the information you've provided in your question. Are you sure you've copied the code in the answer correctly? @ImDarkk